# Gaining Faith/founding religions on King (or higher) difficulties

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

This wasn't really a problem on Prince, but the AI is founding pantheons ridiculously quickly on King. I'll start researching Pottery first and before I even complete that 3 other civilizations have founded Pantheons and snagged the the beliefs that I wanted.

How can I snag beliefs as quickly as the AI does on King?

Right now it seems the only thing I can do is hope for for a faith CS or ancient ruin.

Comment: It's entirely possible that the AI civs beating you to Pantheons are the exceptionally Faith-centric civs, like the Celts, the Maya, and the Ethiopians. Also, the AI on King and above starts with the Pottery tech researched right off the bat, and enjoys bonuses to their production, meaning they can get Shrines a lot faster than you can.

Comment: What's your actual question?  How to beat them?  How to stop them?  Something else?

Answer (score 6):

You need to accept that you won't get the first pantheon, or the first religion, barring very good luck. You won't get your favorite beliefs on the higher difficulty. Its just not possible to beat the AI. Watching a few Diety Lets Plays, they were only able to get the very last pantheon, even though they were pushing religion aggressively. Like Rilgon said, if you want the choice beliefs you can pick a faith-based civ, but even then you probably won't be first or even second.